# Spread a list into parent sexp

Tags: lisp, scheme, common-lisp

Is there a form in any lisp that could "spread" a list in the parent sexp? Like:

```
(+ (spread '(1 2 3))) -> (+ 1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two way to do it. Which is better depends on what you want in the end.

Generally, you can use `,@` inside `` ` `` (backquote). The form following `,@` is evaluated to produce a list, which is then spliced into the template:

```
* `(+ ,@'(1 2 3))
(+ 1 2 3)

* (eval `(+ ,@'(1 2 3)))
6
```

Or, if you just want to call a function with its arguments which are packed in a list, it will be more convenient to use the `apply` function:

```
* (apply #'+ '(1 2 3))
6
```

Comment: oh! i kept seeing `,@` in source files and examples, but i never did figure out what it did (until now). thank you!

Comment: Yeah, if you're just trying to have this passed in to a function like `+`, then the `apply` part of this answer is very likely what's wanted.

Comment: very good ! i second the apply approach though cause it's schemer. ;)