# Unquote splice without unquote splice?

Tags: common-lisp

Is it possible to write the following without using backquote?

```lisp
(defmacro while (test &rest body)
  `(do ()
       ((not ,test))
     ,@body))
```

Thought I'd try this as an experiment to understand benefit of backquote.

I got as far as this:

```lisp
(let* ((test '(> 10))
       (x 0)
       (body '((princ x) (incf x))))
  (list 'do nil (list (list 'not test))))
```

Which successfully generates:

```lisp
(DO NIL ((NOT (> 10))))
```

To finish this I need a way to spread the `n` elements of the list `body` into the generated form. 
I know that's the entire purpose of the unquote splice `,@` but is this actually impossible without it? Curious... It's similar to what `apply` [does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015885/spread-a-list-into-parent-sexp) but I don't want to call a function at this point obviously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the body contains the remaining forms to be evaluated, and can be added with `LIST*`:

```
(let* ((test '(> 10))
       (x 0)
       (body '((princ x) (incf x))))
  (list* 'do
         nil   
         (list (list 'not test))
         body))
```

Another example, where the spliced list is not at the end:

```
`(,x ,@y ,z)
```

The above can be written without backquotes as:

```
(list* x (append y (list z)))
```